# Leaflet Google Map plugin freezes on pinch zoom

Tags: google-maps-api-3, ios6, leaflet, pinchzoom

the shramov/leaflet-plugins Google Layer used to work with Leaflet 0.5.1. However, with Leaflet 0.6.4, it freezes when using pinch zoom in the iOS Simulator 6.1. Zoom buttons and double click zoom work fine.

To reproduce the issue, simply download the repo at https://github.com/shramov/leaflet-plugins and apply the corresponding Leaflet version to the examples/google.html and load in iOS Simulator

I know that this plugin is not supported by Leaflet, but I was looking for help on how to debug this since it only happens with pinch zoom. I'm wondering what breaking changes could have been done to the zoom animation since Leaflet 0.5.1. I think the plugin is trying to trigger a zoom before the end of the zoom animation. Any help would be appreciated.

Link to issue: https://github.com/shramov/leaflet-plugins/issues/62

Thanks,

Nick,

Answer (score 1):

Check to see what your options are when you are instantiating the L.map object. Pinch/zoom was freezing up for me on a variety of mobile devices with

zoomAnimation: false

in my options. When I changed it to true, the freezes went away. I believe that there are a number of bugs in 0.6.4 related to animation, with this one being the worst. For myself I have reverted back to 0.5.1. I like the animation options that 0.6.4 provides, but it seems that they are not yet fully baked.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a "fix". However, the pinch zoom does NOT crash if I add a polyline for example.